# c# How to store login information while web scraping

Tags: c#, cookies, authentication, web-scraping, web-crawler

Im writing a web-crawler in c#. So far in my pogram i can scan the websites source code. For my intended website i need to be logged in to access the a statics page. However with my code, i login just fine and can scan the source code, However when i navitged to the download page, i got an error. I think its because i need to somehow tell the website that im still login in. How do i do that?

Current code .

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace WebCraler
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static string username = "john" ;
        static string password = "123"; 

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Test login");
            String Page = GetWebText("http://localhost/PHP/Login/userStats.php");
            Console.WriteLine (Page);

            Console.WriteLine ("Test Login");
            String response = loginResponse(); 
            Console.WriteLine (response);
        }

        public static string GetWebText(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string htmlText="";
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null){
                if(line.Contains("<td>"))
                {
                    //htmlText += "\n *****Found Andrew Kralovec****** \n";
                }
                htmlText += line+"\n";
            }
            //string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return htmlText;
        }

        private static String loginResponse()
        {
            try{

                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string postData = "myusername=" + username + "&mypassword=" + password;
                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/PHP/Login/check_login.php");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;

                Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Close();

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader steamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
                String htmlRespones = steamReader.ReadToEnd();

                steamReader.Close();
                stream.Close();

                return htmlRespones ; 


            }catch{
                String htmlRespones = "Catch Error"; 
                return htmlRespones ; 

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please add the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

When you login to a website, the server will issue a cookie which must be re-sent on subsequent requests so the server knows you're logged-in (otherwise you get redirected to the login page or some other error).

By default, `HttpWebRequest` does not preserve cookies between requests, you need to manage this yourself:

```
private CookieContainer sessionCookies = new CookieContainer();

public void MakeRequest() {
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create();
    request.CookieContainer = this.sessionCookies;
    // your code here
    request.GetResponse();
}
```

Comment: Im kinda confused on cookies. What code goes below the //your code here. i'm using  WebRequest  for the login to handle the post method.

Answer (score 0):

Dai has rightly presented the way to leverage cookies. Yet, besides loading cookeis into request, you also need to store new arrived cookies into a CookieContainer variable:

```
private CookieContainer sessionCookies = new CookieContainer();

public static string GetWebText(string url) {
   HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create();
   request.CookieContainer = this.sessionCookies; // loading cookies in
   WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
   // now we need to store cookies received from server into the sessionCookies variable
   this.sessionCookies = response.GetCoookies(); // GetCoookies() method or similar, check C# specification
   ...
   return htmlText;
}
```

`// your code here` - might be just anything (nothing) in between request and response. I've removed it.

Comment: There is no such thing as    this.sessionCookies = response.GetCoookies();

Comment: @John, how can you be sure that incoming cookies are stored at your web crawler?